# Move Listview with datatable into another listview

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listview

I want to move the selected row to the listview beside it. The source listview has FullRowSelect = true and MultiSelect = false. The source listview is populated via Data table from Database.

[image: Listview]

Here is what i have so far. It only moves the selected item. I want it to move the whole selected row.

```
private static void MoveSelectedItems(ListView source, ListView target)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < source.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (source.Items[i].Selected)
            {
                target.Items.Add(source.Items[i]);

            }
        }
    }
```

This is what happens when i run the code.

[image: Output]

Comment: how do you populate the first listview?

Comment: From Mysql Database

Comment: @mm8 i was experimenting on the code by that time forgot to change it back to that. With that code it still only moves 1 item not the whole row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, since you have set `MultiSelect` to false, you dont need the loop to iterate over all items.

Secondly, the moving part is just simple. You take the selected item and add that in the target items. Since your are moving, and not just copying, we will also remove the item from the source listview.

```
private static void MoveSelectedItems(ListView source, ListView target)
{
    if(source.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        ListViewItem selectedItem= source.SelectedItems[0];
        foreach (var subItem in source.SelectedItems[0].SubItems)
        {
             selectedItem.SubItems.Add (subItem);
        }
        source.Items.Remove(selectedItem);
        target.Items.Add(selectedItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is still moving only 1 of the selected item. 
Ex. i click on the 1st row, only the 1st item of the first column is moved. Thank you for the answer tho

Comment: Im still having the same problem. Maybe my 2nd listview is wrong? because it isnt even displaying the column name for the item. Just the item. See picture in question, it is the same output with your code.

Comment: You need to add columns in your target ListView

Comment: I found the problem, it was so simple. I had to set the View property of the listview. Code works perfectly now thanks.